# mysqli_*somemethod*()_ expect parameter

Tags: php, mysqli, parameters

First of all, I was googling it for over 4 hours. Found dozen of similar questions even here on stackoverflow, but I really couldnt find the solution. So thats why im  writing new question.. im pretty much a newbie, and i really tried everything I could on my own and with the answers I found here, but nothing seems to be working.
Btw, sorry for my broken english..

so here are my errors when i try to submit my new user registration inputs to the database:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\epo\insert.php on line 17

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\epo\insert.php on line 18

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\epo\insert.php on line 28

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\epo\insert.php on line 29

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\epo\insert.php on line 30

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\epo\insert.php on line 31

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\epo\insert.php on line 36

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\epo\insert.php on line 39
Neuspesno upisivanje u bazu podataka!
```

here is the db connection code (konekcija.php) :

```
<?php
ob_start();


if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}


$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db_name = 'epo';

$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

if(!$connection){
    die("CONNECTION TO DB FAILED. " . mysqli_error($connection));
}


?>
```

here's the registration form (reg.php) file :

```
<?php include("insert.php"); ?>

<?php include("index.php");?>

   <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
        <h3>Registarcija korisnika za EPO sistem</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="row registracija">
       <div class="row">
           <h3>Dobrodosli, molimo Vas, popunite polja kako biste se registrovali.</h3>
       </div>

        <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">


            <?php echo $errordanger; ?> 
            <?php echo $uspehreg; ?> 


            <div class="row form-group inputgrp">
                <label for="" class="col-sm-2">Ime: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                   <input type="text" name="ime" id="ime" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

        <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

            <div class="row form-group inputgrp">
                <label for="" class="col-sm-2">Prezime: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                   <input type="text" name="prezime" id="prezime" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>


        <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

            <div class="row form-group inputgrp">
                <label for="" class="col-sm-2">E-mail: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                   <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>


        <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

            <div class="row form-group inputgrp">
                <label for="" class="col-sm-2">Sifra: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                   <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

        <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

            <div class="row form-group" style="margin: 0px 10px 20px 10px">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Registruj se" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>




</div>
```

and here's the insert script (insert.php) :

```
<?php
    global $connection;
    global $errordanger, $uspehreg;

    $fname = $lname = $email = $password = "";


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $ime = $_POST['ime'];
        $prezime = $_POST['prezime'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $passw = $_POST['password'];

        //Provera da li korisnik vec postoji


        $sql_query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE email = '{$email}' ");
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($sql_query);


        if($count > 0){

            $errordanger = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
             Korisnik sa tom email adresom vec postoji!
            </div>";
        }else{

            $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $ime);
            $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $prezime);
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $email);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $passw);


        $sql = "INSERT INTO signup(email, ime, prezime, password, date_time) VALUES ('{$email}' , '{$ime}', '{$prezime}', '{$passw}', now()) ";

        $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

        if(!$query){
            die(" Neuspesno upisivanje u bazu podataka! " . mysqli_error($connection));

        }else{
            $uspehreg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
  <strong>Uspesno ste se registrovali!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
</div>";

      }    

    }
 }

?>
```

Comment: `global $connection` is null. Maybe you forgot to require the db connection code?

Comment: what is file name which contains `db connection code` ?

Comment: Well, im following some course, and He didnt require it, and I've checked 10 times we have exact same lines of codes.

Comment: @Alex its ' konekcija.php '

Comment: What is the db connection file called?

Comment: @JordanS it's ' konekcija.php '

Comment: @james beleive me james, I red every answer thats on the link you provided. I tried various fixes, nothing helped me..

Comment: And when and where do you `include ('konekcija.php')` ?

Comment: So, you've been told that the connection script needs to be include()d from the registration script. What's your progress on this attempt? How else did you imagine the $connection variable would get set? Also, please pick up another tutorial. Mysqli and manual escaping are no longer a thing.

Comment: @james there are actually 3 fiels, I just didnt CTRL+K them  in a good way, I edited it now.

Comment: @Alex that fixed a problem buddy! Many thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code in `insert.php`:

```
global $connection;

$sql_query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE email = '{$email}' ");
```

Given you do not initiate any scope (a function, class, or namespace) then the `global` keyword is pointless, but anyway.

You're not including the file which sets the `$connection` variable.

in `reg.php` you include `insert.php`, this latter file relies upon the `$connection` variable but that is set in `konekcija.php` but you do not include that file, so `$connection` has no value.

Comment: Yes, I understood it by myself with Alex's help few minutes ago. I do understand that, just wasn't watching about that, since I was sure I included it. Silly of me..
Anyway, Im mega grateful for your nice explanation!

Comment: Yeah such things happen :) Pro tip would be to change how you go about including files that are critical to other things. For example `reg.php` is including mandatory files, but I'm sure other parts of your site will need them too, such as the DB connect one. It's easy to forget (as you found out) but also clunky and not ideal manually including them one by one every time you need them.

Comment: Classes (can usually) make this simpler as you can just import, and potentially initially load your main always-used things at the top and later on when you need them they're there (frameworks do this to a degree). At the least, have a file which includes all your main things and include that one file once in all files which need such things like DB conn etc (tho this is an old style way of doing it)

Comment: Noted @james, as i said Im a newbie, and even this that I'm doing is pretty much info at once tbh, but over the time, Im sure things will be way morebetter and easier your way, so Ill follow your tips for sure buddy!

Answer (score -2):

So how stup*d am I guys? I havent included my db connection file into the insert.php scripts. Works like a charm since I included it!

@Alex noticed it, so thank You again buddy! I can't express how grateful and happy I am now!

Answer (score -3):

Try to Change the SQL QUERY in insert.php in

```
$sql_query=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE email = '$email' ") ;
```

Comment: Not a solution.

Comment: Yep, I'm getting the same errors.. nothing has changed

Comment: If you know the actual correct solution then posting as an answer is fine, otherwise you need to make comments to get clarification